# Why won't the second scanf() execute

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to execute this block of code.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void)
{       

     printf("Start from here\n");
     int e, f, g, h;

     scanf("%d,%d", &e, &f);
     scanf("%d, %d", &g, &h);

     printf("%d %d %d %d", e, f, g, h);
}
```

When I input `2,0` or something that matches the format string in the first `scanf()`, the second `scanf()` also executes.

However, if I input something like `2-0` in the first `scanf()`, the program skips the second `scanf()` and goes straight to the `printf()`

For example, here's the input and output of a sample run of the program. The second line is the input.

```
Start from here
1-2  
1 0 -2 -856016624u
```

Notice how the program completely skipped the second `scanf()`, and went straight to the `printf()`. Why is the second `scanf()` being skipped over here?

Comment: `1-2` should be `1,-2`? That is, a comma between the numbers. Because that is what you told `scanf` to expect.

Comment: your second `scanf` is being executed. `e` gets `1` and `g` gets `-2`

Comment: Why are you not checking the return values from `scanf`? Might be handy to read the manual page

Comment: FALSE.  The program does not 'skip' the second `scanf` — the program executes it, but the results are different from what you expect. Just read a manual about `scanf()` to understand what happens when you provide an input incompatible with the format, and how to detect and handle the error.

Comment: this is one of the many times when checking the returned value (not the parameter value) from `scanf()` would have informed the code of the failure to read both parameters in the first call to `scanf()`  and the failure of the second call to `scanf()` to read both parameters

Answer (score 21):

`scanf`'s format string cares about the non-format specifiers in it too. When you write "1-2" the first scanf will read "1", then look for a comma. It won't find one, so it'll give up. Now, the second scanf will see "-2" and then look for a comma. It won't find one, so it'll give up.

The end result is that the other two variables won't get set so they end up being whatever garbage is in their memory location at execution time.

You can avoid this by checking the return value of scanf. It'll tell you how many values it found. Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void)
{       

     printf("Start from here\n");
     int e, f, g, h;

     if (scanf("%d,%d", &e, &f) != 2) { /* error handling */ }
     if (scanf("%d, %d", &g, &h) != 2) { /* error handling */ }

     printf("%d %d %d %d", e, f, g, h);
}
```

Comment: Note: As part of *error handling*, you might need to discard some user input! That can be done using a `getchar` loop, or `scanf("%*[^\n]"); getchar();` for example...

Comment: Also note: the space, in this case, is semantically meaningless; both format strings are functionally equivalent as `%d` will implicitly discard leading whitespace *anyway*.

Comment: Good to know, removed the bit about the format strings.

Comment: Why use `while` instead of `if`?

Comment: If you flush stdin where I wrote `/* error handling */` as Seb suggested, you can prompt the user again for input (if you don't, you'll probably just get an infinite loop). Using `if` will skip to the next scanf (or to the print, which will print garbage).

Comment: This is why you should avoid scanf for input that may be wrong unless you really understand it, and it's usually easier to just write your own parser.

Comment: Downvoted for the use of `while` instead of `if`. Change that to an if statement. Otherwise, this is a good answer.

Comment: Changed it to use `if` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Remove a **comma** between the two format specifier.

```
scanf("%d %d", &e, &f); // Remove comma in first argument of scanf
scanf("%d %d", &g, &h);  // Remove comma in first argument of scanf
        ^^^
      Remove comma between two numbers
```

Because `scanf` will only skip **white space** and the `comma` is not **white space**.

What actually happens when you ask `scanf` to read numeric data is that it first skips any white space it finds and then it reads characters until the character it reads cannot form part of a number.

In this case, when it encounters the **comma**, it stops reading. Since it has not read any digits, there is no number for it to store, so it simply leaves the original value.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `scanf("%d, %d",&e,&f)` is in this way, so you should give your input like: `1,2` or `2,3` etc

If you want your input to be given like `0-2` or `2-4`, then your scanf must be like this :  `scanf("%d-%d",&e,&f)`.

In this way, it will not be skipped.